# javascript pattern matching

Tags: javascript, regex, pattern-matching

matchArray becomes null for input like `asklas@(((#` How do I correct this behavior? I only want to allow characters and numbers..

```
function validateName(name) {
    debug(name);
    var namePat = /^(\[A-Za-z0-9]*)$/ ;
    var matchArray = name.match(namePat);
    if (!matchArray){
        debug ("Invalid name,", name );
        return false;
    } 
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is one erroneous backslash in your regex. It should be

```
var namePat = /^[A-Za-z0-9]*$/;
```

(and you don't need the capturing parentheses, either).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you want in this case... if you want a boolean output, use .test:

```
namePat.test(name)
```

... but null will work for your test `(!matchArray)` just fine.

It does seem like you have a typo in your regular expression - you'll want to get rid of the backslash before the opening bracket...